# Getting a predictable IP in LXC guest running Ubuntu bionic

Tags: networking, lxc

I have two (unprivileged) LXC guests running Ubuntu xenial and Ubuntu bionic 
both installed and configured in the same way (at least I thought so). The xenial guest works as expected always gets the same ip, so I just put a line in `/etc/hosts` for it, and then I can `ssh` into it when started.

But the guest running Ubuntu bionic gets a new ip each time I start it :-(

I thought this was a consequence of Ubuntu changing to netplan, so I dug a little into that (below), but it seems not to be the case, so you can probably skip to the last paragraph.

Both guests have a this (different MAC addresses of course) in the LXC configuration:

```
# Network configuration
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:FF:6e:d1:58:d2
```

The xenial guest has an `/etc/network/interfaces` that looks like:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

The bionic guest has the following in `/etc/netplan/10-lxc.yaml`:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    eth0: {dhcp4: true}
  version: 2
```

(I've not familiarised myself much with netplan yet, but it seems to me to say the same).

On both guests the configured MAC is assigned to eth1, while eth0 gets a new MAC address every time, but somehow the xenial guest gets the same IP anyway (and that's why I no longer think netplan is to blame).

I also have an LXC guest running Debian Stretch (the host does so too), that works (in this regard) much like the xenial guest.

So what can I have done wrong? And how do I get a predictable ip in the bionic guest?

Comment: I don't know why the xenial guest receives the same IP, but using static network configuration should do the trick (i.e. no DHCP).

Comment: Wonder why I hadn't thought of that before. A static configuration worked (when I got the netplan syntax right).